# What is the Alternative to Federated Authentication in ASP.Net Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, federated-identity

I have a Web API (.Net 4.6) which authenticates my users using the FederatedAuthentication (System.IdentityModel.Services), and now I am trying to port it to ASP.Net Core   2.2 Web API.

Here is my existing code to generate the FedAuth token cookie:

1. AuthController.cs

```
//... Create new Identity and Claims Principal.
ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(User.Identity);
ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);

claimsIdentity.AddClaims(__getClaims());
claimsPrincipal.AddIdentity(claimsIdentity);

//... Create a new Session Security Token. 
  var token = FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.CreateSessionSecurityToken(
claimsPrincipal, "MyAPP", DateTime.UtcNow, DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(expirationTime), false);

//... Write a cookie.
FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.
AuthenticateSessionSecurityToken(token, true);
```

And in the Web.config:

```
<configSections>
    <!--WIF 4.5 sections -->
    <section name="system.identityModel" type="System.IdentityModel.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelSection, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <section name="system.identityModel.services" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelServicesSection, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
</configSections>

<modules>
  <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
</modules>

<system.identityModel>
    <identityConfiguration>
      <securityTokenHandlers>
        <remove type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <add type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Tokens.MachineKeySessionSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </securityTokenHandlers>
    </identityConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel>
```

Since Claims Identity and Claims Principal is used by all of my relying applications, I want to continue using the same in ASP.net core too.

So, my question here is that, what is the way to create a session security token 
(cookie) with claims Identity in ASP.net core web API?

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe I got what I was looking for;
Here are the two good articles I found out to start with:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-2.2
2. https://jonhilton.net/2017/10/11/secure-your-asp.net-core-2.0-api-part-1-issuing-a-jwt/

EDIT: The second link was updated by their author that resulted in 404 error. I found the working link and updated back here.

NOTE: The reason I have posted only links here to answer my own question is that they are long articles and has to be read in length to understand the subject.

Comment: When answering a question such as this, it is best to include the relevant text in addition to the link, so that if the link disappears, the answer is still available.  In this case, the jonhilton.net link is no longer working.